# swift tableview is not reloading after deleting cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have Tableview created in storyboard . when I try to delete the cell in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]` Table is not reloading immediately after deleting. It will be successfully deleted in Database also.
 When I close the view and come back then it will be updated. Where am I going wrong?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Löschen") { (rowAction, indexPath) in


            let Info: NSDictionary = self.finaltaskValue[indexPath.item] as! NSDictionary
            let pwid = Info["pwid"] as! String
            self.finaltaskValue.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.finalTasktableView.beginUpdates()
            self.finalTasktableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            self.finalTasktableView.endUpdates()


            let url = URL(string: "...php")

            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let body = "parameters"

            request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                if error == nil {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        do{
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary


                            guard let parseJSON = json else {
                                print("")
                                return
                            }

                           DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            self.finalTasktableView.reloadData()
                            })

                        }catch {
                            //print("Caught an error: \(error)")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                let message = "Server ist Offline! Wir arbeiten mit hochdruck dran alles zu reparieren"

                        }
                    })

                }else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = error!.localizedDescription


                }

                }.resume()
        }


    deleteAction.backgroundColor = colorDarkGreen
    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Comment: Don't reload the table view after using `deleteRows(at`. This method does update the UI. Btw delete `begin-/endUpdates()`. Both lines have no effect. And what is the purpose to dispatch `dataTask` to the **main** thread? `dataTask` uses its own thread anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to check your tableview get data from the final task value.
2) Please when you perform delete action don't use begin update and begin end update method please user reload method which shown here.

```
finaltasktableview.reloadData()
```

3) I don't understand why you define url request here?
4) your request not using any parameter of this method or delete logic parameter also not included. check your request response fill again that data which you want to delete.

Comment: 1) yes finalTasktableView gets value from finaltaskvalue. 3) & 4) I do send the parameters here to delete the row in mysql (I have  hidden the parameters in Query). deleting in database is successful. Only problem is  table is not reloading.

Comment: in your array delete that value ? check this by debug. And also try this one please check your outlets and and also delegate and datasource. and try to break outlets and re join them. and in your code please add class name: UITableviewdelegate , UItableviewDatasource.

Comment: yes its deleting from array. I did break outlets and rejoined. still its same

Answer (score 0):

1) I agree finaltasktableview.reloadData()
is better for relatively small tables.

2) You issue a network call, but the first                   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

is useless.